# How can I create a 2d array with labels, without numpy or pandas, from two lists for Python?

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

Let's say I have scores for five Rock, Paper, Scissors games that look like this:

```
player_score = [1,0,1,1,0]
cpu_score = [0,1,0,0,1]
```

I want to make a 2d array (without numpy or pandas) that keeps a record of the games played(Like a scoreboard). So the final output would look 'something' resembled to this:

```
         G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 

Player   1  0  1  1  0 
CPU      0  1  0  0  1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: No (I updated my question, forgot about pandas) I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "************************", line 11, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: you didn't specify anything. what are the labels? what is your desired behavior? the output you showed doesn't answer those questions. as is, your question is unclear/too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy and pandas are powerful tools in Python programming, but trying working without them helps to learn better. They provide a diversity of useful functions and object classes, to work without which means that you may have to define your own.

To display the scoreboard that you wish, I'd recommend that you define your own scoreboard class. I'll give you an example like this:

```
class ScoreBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_score = [1,0,1,1,0]
        self.cpu_score = [0,1,0,0,1]

    def __str__(self):
        string = '\t'
        for i in range(len(self.player_score)):
            string += 'G%d '%(i+1)
        string = string + '\n\nPlayer\t'
        for i in range(len(self.player_score)):
            string += '%d  '%self.player_score[i]
        string = string + '\nCPU\t'
        for i in range(len(self.cpu_score)):
            string += '%d  '%self.cpu_score[i]
        return string

    def record_score(self, player_score, cpu_score):
        self.player_score.append(player_score)
        self.cpu_score.append(cpu_score)
```

and if you

```
a = ScoreBoard()
print(a)
a.record_score(1, 0)
print(a)
```

, this would be shown:

```
        G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 

Player  1  0  1  1  0  
CPU     0  1  0  0  1 
        G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6

Player  1  0  1  1  0  1
CPU     0  1  0  0  1  0
```

Obviously, more should be done to make this class work well.

1) The initial player_score and cpu_score have to be []

2) What if the scoreboard is empty? When it's empty, would you decorate the string output?

3) Is there a possibility that it's a draw, like Rock vs. Rock? If not, cpu_score can be calculated when you have player_score. In that case, one of these two is not necessary.

4) Perhaps it can become a scoreboard for more games where there are more players?

5) Perhaps you can even define your own labeled 2D arrays, like pandas.DataFrame?

If you haven't learned about Object-Oreinted-Programming in Python, you're free to ask. You can also learn more in [Python Programming Tutorials](https://pythonprogramming.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a DataFrame?

```
import pandas as pd
player_score = [1,0,1,1,0]
cpu_score = [0,1,0,0,1]

df = pd.DataFrame([player_score, cpu_score])
df.columns = ["G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5"]
df.index = ['Player', 'CPU']

print(df)
```

gives

```
              G1  G2  G3  G4  G5
Player         1   0   1   1   0
CPU            0   1   0   0   1
```